# How to change the scope of a variable in a function? Python

Tags: python, function, scope

This may seem like a really stupid question but I am confused regarding the scope rules in Python. In the following example I send two variables (x,y) with values to a function which is supposed to change their values. When I print the results the variables had not changed.

```
def func1(x,y):
    x=200
    y=300

x=2
y=3

func1(x,y)

print x,y #prints 2,3
```

Now if this were C++ I would send them by reference (&) to that function and therefore be able to change their values. So what's the equivilant in Python? and more important, what actually happens when you send objects to function? does Python make new references to these objects?

Comment: Also, [Python: How do I pass a variable by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/395760).

Comment: **All** Python names are references to objects. Function arguments are merely bound to the objects passed in. You don't get a memory location, you always dereference the name when using it in expressions. Assignment is rebinding, not altering the original memory location. Thus `x = 200` is creating a new object (`int(200)`), and storing a reference to that object in `x`.

Comment: Inner scopes have implicit permission to *access* variables from outer scopes, but need explicit permission to *modify* variables from outer scopes.  That's about as succinctly as I can put it.

Comment: (CPython may choose to reuse existing `int()` objects here, but that's an implementation detail).

Comment: So, although the local names `x` and `y` inside `func1` start being bound to the same `int()` objects as the global `x` and `y` names in the module scope, by assigning to them inside the function you only rebound the local names. The global names still refer to their original values.

Comment: So how do you change the reference of the original variables with the use of a function?

Comment: @Reboot_87 take some time and read the duplicate threads linked up top.  Then, if you're still lost, google the `global` keyword.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Think of them as being part of the function. When the function ends, all its variables die too.

```
x=2
y=3

def func(x,y):
    x=200
    y=300

func(x,y) #inside this function, x=200 and y=300
#but by this line the function is over and those new values are discarded
print(x,y) #so this is looking at the outer scope again
```

If you want a function to modify a value in exactly the way you have written it, you could use a `global` but this is VERY bad practice.

```
def func(x,y):
    global x #these tell the function to look at the outer scope 
    global y #and use those references to x and y, not the inner scope
    x=200
    y=300

func(x,y)
print(x,y) #prints 200 300
```

The problem with this is that it makes debugging a nightmare in the best case, and utterly incomprehensibly impossible in the worst case. Things like these are commonly known as "side effects" in functions -- setting a value you don't need set and doing so without explicitly returning it is kind of a Bad Thing. Generally the only functions you should write that modify items in-place are object methods (things like `[].append()` modify the list because it's silly to return a new list instead!)

The RIGHT way to do something like this would be to use a return value. Try something like

```
def func(x,y):
    x = x+200 #this can be written x += 200
    y = y+300 #as above: y += 300
    return (x,y) #returns a tuple (x,y)

x = 2
y = 3
func(x,y) # returns (202, 303)
print(x,y) #prints 2 3
```

Why didn't that work? Well because you never told the program to DO anything with that tuple `(202, 303)`, just to calculate it. Let's assign it now

```
#func as defined above

x=2 ; y=3
x,y = func(x,y) #this unpacks the tuple (202,303) into two values and x and y
print(x,y) #prints 202 303
```

Comment: how would you change x,y with the use of a function?

Comment: Explicitly `return x, y` at the end of your function then call `x, y = func(x, y)`

Comment: @Reboot_87: you can't; the objects you're passing in are immutable and it's therefore impossible to change them, and you can't re-bind the names in the outer scope *just* based on what's passed in. (You can use the `global` keyword to rebind the names `x` and `y` globally, but that would happen regardless of what objects were passed in; in that case func(a, b) would just modify x and y...

Comment: @Reboot_87 I made a sizeable edit with different approaches. Try it all. DON'T use a `global` if you can POSSIBLY help it -- it's awful practice and makes debugging just shy of herculean.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. It made the whole subject clear to me

Comment: @Reboot_87 to me it helps to think of functions like a builder. You don't give your builder the numbers `2` and `3` and have him change those numbers, you give your builder blueprints. "Hey man," you might say, "I want you to make me something that looks kinda like these things here, but different." Then when he's done, the builder comes back to say "Here ya go buddy, here's a *NEW OBJECT* I made that looks kinda like what you showed me!"

Comment: This as opposed to object methods, where you tell an object (a list, or something you've made, or etc) "Hey man, I know you're cool chilling here being an object, but I need you to go ahead and do something for me." Then the object can operate on itself -- it doesn't have to build a new copy of itself to do that.